# Yii2 get user attributes from google authclient login

Tags: php, yii2, google-signin

I am using google authclient login in my application.Google login is working perfectly but I am unable to get the user attributes.
**web.php**

```
 'google' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
            'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'scope'=>' https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
            'returnUrl'=>'https://localhost/mysite',
        ],
```

**sitecontroller.php**

```
 public function actions()
{
    return [

        'auth' => [
            'class' =>'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [
            $this, 'successCallback'
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

**successcallback()**

```
public function successCallback($client)
{

    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
    // print_r($attributes);die();
    // user login or signup comes here
   // print_r($attributes['email']);die();
    $user_email = $attributes['email'];
    $user_name = $attributes['name'];
    // echo $user_email;echo '<br>';
    // echo $user_name;
    // die();

    $user = User::find()->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->one();
    $count = count($user);
    if ($count == 0 ){
        return $this->redirect(['user/create?email='.$user_email.'&name='.$user_name.'']);
    }else{
        return Yii::$app->user->login($user);
        //echo Yii::$app->user->identity->id;die();
    }
```

Could any one help me to achieve this..
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your returnUrl in web.php this : https://test.com/site/auth?authclient=google

your code must be like below :

```
 'google' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Google',
        'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'returnUrl'=>'https://test.com/site/auth?authclient=google',
    ],
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.